# How to expanding bootstrap form like stackoverflow search form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'am actually new with CSS, and have no idea to create a input like stackoverflow search form, I think it can be done with jquery trigger by button and change width value of that form?? Any suggestion or solutions?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/117591

Comment: Thanks! this was actually what I want :D

Comment: but how about custom triggerrer for example I will add search icon and if I clik the icon that will show the form and expanding slowly?

Comment: if you see code you can see it's woking by changing width with transition.you can change width using css or javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .form-control{
  width:100px;

  }
 .form-control:focus{
  width:400px;
  outline:none;
      transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>



    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### some idea for you, this codepen link:

#### http://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/EmyRaG

or use the following, check in full page.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px
}

div#bar {
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 40px 40px -20px #eee;
  padding-right: 200px;
}

div#bar > div {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px
}

div#bar input, div#bar ul {
  float: right;
}

div#bar input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 275px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
  transition: all .7s
}

div#bar input:focus {
  width: 625px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20
}

div#bar input:focus + ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 300px;
  opacity: 0
}

div#bar ul {
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .35s
}

div#bar ul li {
  float: right;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <ul>
      <li>Questions</li>
      <li>Jobs</li>
      <li>Documentation</li>
      <li>Tags</li>
      <li>Users</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```